# com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task

Tags: java, jquery, usb, webcam

Here I have written some code to capture the image from USBcam using java.

**Below is the code:**

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File("d:/hello-world1.png"));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I have added 3 jars what ever required,
but when running the application, image is not getting,
Exception is raised.

**Below is the Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:57)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:120)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:35)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.open(WebcamOpenTask.java:20)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:187)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:147)
    at ImageCapture.main(ImageCapture.java:16)
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot start native grabber!
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice.open(WebcamDefaultDevice.java:220)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.handle(WebcamOpenTask.java:38)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest me any idea where am putting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TakePictureExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();

        webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(1024,768));

        webcam.open(false);

        // get image
        BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();

        // save image to PNG file
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @SSpoke am getting same exception

Comment: try commenting out `webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(1024,768));`

Comment: Okay your problem is `Cannot start native grabber!` https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/webcam/ds/buildin/WebcamDefaultDevice.java try maybe making the `setViewSize` smaller if that doesn't help look at that create new issue here, https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a bit late but for everyone having this issue in Windows 10: Check if your 'data protection settings for the `camera`. Maybe there the access for programs is blocked, which can result in the error.